# Fixing the size of a jButton with full screen and GridBagConstrains

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am trying to have my jButton really small. It works if I change the margins (the 250 in the example). But this will not work with variable screen size. Any other method?

```
startButton = new JButton("Start");
//this is not taking:
startButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 40));

contentPanel.add(startButton, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(150, 250, 0, 250), 0, 0));
```

As far as I understand the 250 are left and right margin. Of course by changing these the size changes. But since it's full screen this is not a robust way to do it. Any ideas on how to make the button minimal size and then just center it?

Comment: Check out the [`fill` parameter of the `GridBagConstraints`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html#gridbagConstraints). Change `GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL` to GridBagConstraints.NONE` and remove silly margins.

Comment: I tried:              contentPanel.add(startButton, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, new Insets(150, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0)); That does it. Except now the button is too small for the text. the setSize doesn't seem to stick.

Comment: Ok, worked with: startButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 40));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resize the button with:

```
 contentPanel.add(buttonsPanel, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(100, 100, 0, 100), 0, 0));

startButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 40));
```